# How to count employee readings in current month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, view, count

I'm trying to work out how to make this view for my database

The number of meters read in the current month by each of the meter
readers (this view should be able to be used at any time without having to
be changed to accommodate the date).

The main trouble I'm having is counting how many times the employee has read a meter in the month. I'm using oracle and sql developer.

These are my tables:

```
a2_METERREADER

 - EMPLOYEEID
 - FIRSTNAME
 - LASTNAME

a2_READING

 - READINGID
 - METERID
 - EMPLOYEEID
 - BILLNUMBER
 - READING
 - DATERECORD

a2_Watermeter

 - METERID
 - ADDRESS
 - SUBURB
 - POSTCODE
 - STATUS
 - CUSTOMERID
 - REPLACE
 - INSTALLDATE
```

Comment: can add some data please :) i mean table structure and sample records.

Comment: let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the meter reader and reading tables and count the number of rows, grouped by employee for the month in question.

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT reader.EMPLOYEEID, COUNT(reading.READINGID)
FROM a2_METERREADER reader, a2_READING reading
WHERE reader.EMPLOYEEID = reading.EMPLOYEEID
AND YEAR(reading.DATERECORD) = YEAR(SYSDATE)
AND MONTH(reading.DATERECORD) = MONTH(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY reader.EMPLOYEEID
```

Comment: also i need help on the date aspect of the question, i cant get it to read todays month

Comment: Thankyou, but is there no way of it reading in the date from windows?

Comment: Yes you can. With SYSDATE which gives you the current Date from Windows. If you only need EMPLOYEEID I dont see the reason for a JOIN either. Check my answer below I believe it gives you what you need.
More Dynamically.

Comment: Yes you can using SYSDATE as pana said. Also he is correct about the join, providing you only want to display the employees ID and not their name.

Answer (score 2):

IF your daterecord is a DATE then to access current month from Windows you can do this.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, COUNT(*)
FROM a2_READING
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATERECORD, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
```

This way you eliminate the days from DATERECORD (only keeps months and year) and it has to be the same with the SYSDATE (Current Date) again converted to keep month and year.

You dont need to join with METERREADER table if you only need the IDs